# "Core" function in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am working on a class project related with Postgres. I want to know what's the "core" function used in Postgres server? I am looking for something corresponding to main() in a simple C program. I want to know the file path and the function name. I am using Postgres 9.3.5, however I assume the "core" function will be unchanged between different revisions.

Please let me know if you are confused by my question.

Thanks.

Edit: [re-posted this on the pgsql-hackers mailing list](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAEHyd7ec-EtYe_yW2QPS+amq__NGP1Lmx=W9iSKqrBkBDyWMhg@mail.gmail.com).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're probably talking about the server event loop.

It depends on the backend type.

For the postmaster, it's `PostmasterMain` in `src/backend/postmaster/postmaster.c` (postmaster startup) then `ServerLoop` in the same file.

For regular worker backends it's `PostgresMain` in `src/backend/tcop/postgres.c`.

Other backends (like the background writer, autovacuum launcher, etc) have their own main loops.

You should really start with the [developer information on the PostgreSQL site](http://www.postgresql.org/developer/), particularly the developer section of the PostgreSQL documentation that discusses PostgreSQL's internals, and the series of presentations and articles available on PostgreSQL's internals.

---

Also, get a good text editor with `ctags`/`cscope` support and get familiar with a debugger like `gdb`. It'll make navigating the sources and stepping through the code way easier. You could've answered this yourself, for example, by:

- Starting a backend and getting its process ID

  ```
  regress=> select pg_backend_pid();
   pg_backend_pid 
  ----------------
             2292
  (1 row)
  ```
- Attaching `gdb`

  ```
  sudo -u postgres gdb -p 2292
  ```
- Getting a backtrace

  ```
  (gdb) bt
  #0  0x0000003bc68f5c3d in __libc_recv (fd=10, buf=buf@entry=0xc3d0a0 <PqRecvBuffer>, n=n@entry=8192, flags=-1, flags@entry=0) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/recv.c:29
  #1  0x00000000005f95f5 in recv (__flags=0, __n=8192, __buf=0xc3d0a0 <PqRecvBuffer>, __fd=<optimized out>) at /usr/include/bits/socket2.h:44
  #2  secure_read (port=0x1db02c0, ptr=0xc3d0a0 <PqRecvBuffer>, len=8192) at be-secure.c:317
  #3  0x0000000000602b53 in pq_recvbuf () at pqcomm.c:854
  #4  0x00000000006037d5 in pq_getbyte () at pqcomm.c:895
  #5  0x00000000006e19a0 in SocketBackend (inBuf=0x7fff2f397b10) at postgres.c:335
  #6  ReadCommand (inBuf=0x7fff2f397b10) at postgres.c:483
  #7  PostgresMain (argc=<optimized out>, argv=argv@entry=0x1d8b2b8, dbname=0x1d8b120 "regress", username=<optimized out>) at postgres.c:3975
  #8  0x0000000000463c51 in BackendRun (port=0x1db02c0) at postmaster.c:4117
  #9  BackendStartup (port=0x1db02c0) at postmaster.c:3791
  #10 ServerLoop () at postmaster.c:1570
  #11 0x00000000006780ee in PostmasterMain (argc=argc@entry=3, argv=argv@entry=0x1d8a2d0) at postmaster.c:1223
  #12 0x00000000004649fb in main (argc=3, argv=0x1d8a2d0) at main.c:227
  ```

Comment: @ZackLi I suggest a good read of http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/internals.html and  https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Developer_FAQ